# Poll software used for live quiz

Tags: software

I was wondering if someone knows what is the name of the app used in the live quiz made in min 4:30 here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pq9LcwC7CoY, or if someone knows a similar app.

The key thing that I'm looking for is that the bar chart doesn't show the answers, while it does show the number of people who have answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Earlier in the video ([at this point](https://youtu.be/pq9LcwC7CoY?t=82)), Grant tells us that the poll is done through [Itempool](https://itempool.com/). You can create an account there and create something called a "live challenge".

Comment: I just tried it out and it works just like in the video. You start a live session, copy and share a link to the live session, then click to begin accepting answers. It shows how many people gave the same unique answers (accepting mathematically equivalent expressions, using an unknown engine), and you can click when to reveal what people answered and the correct answer.

Comment: Damn, so lame. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: Don't feel bad. This is a good question to have here, with its answer, for later.